# Will my wolf getting the kill effect the amount of XP dropped?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Will it affect the amount of experience points received if my wolf kills a mob instead of me in Minecraft PE?

If it does, then by how much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not make a difference.

Comment: Can you back this up with a source or is this your own experience?

Comment: My own experience, I googled for a bit but could not find anything wihch answers the question.

Comment: No problem, but it's good to know it :)